# Call a parameter of a function in another one

Tags: python

I have two function *f1* and *f2* inside of a class.

```
class Ex():
    def f1(self,a):
        ...

    def f2(self)
        print(a)

ex = Ex()
ex.f1(10)
ex.f2()
```

What I want is to get as output of this code *a*, "10".
So, what's the easier way to "transfer" the parameter *a* of *f1* into *f2*, and then print it?

Comment: Check out `**kwargs`

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to achieve?

Comment: let's elaborate: you shouldn't call a parameter of some function. Perhaps, you want to get the default value of a distinct parameter of `function1` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways this could be done. one way would be to make a "setter" in your class:

```
class Ex():
    a = None # deafult value
    def function_1(self,a):
        Ex.a = a
        ...
    def function_2(self)
        print(Ex.a)
```

eg:

```
>>> class foo:
    a = None
    def f(self, a):
        foo.a = a
    def b(self):
        print(foo.a)


>>> f = foo()
>>> f.f(12)
>>> f.b()
12
>>>
```

However, what i suggest you do instead, is to pass the return value of `function_1()` to `function_2()`:

```
class Ex():
    def function_1(self,a):
        ...
        ...
        return a
    def function_2(self, a)
        print(a)
...
...
ex = Ex()
a = ex.function_1()
ex.function_2(a)
```