# How to access variables from other functions in python

Tags: python, function

I've got a function (get_score) that uses variables from other functions(self.__sma) in the same class.

My question: How can I access these variables from the get_score function? (error: global name is not defined).

Also, i heard that using global variables causes a shitstorm(just based from what I read on here). Thanks in advance.

Here is some code:

```
testlist = ['TREE', 'HAPPY']
Class MyStrategy(strategy.BacktestingStrategy):
    def __init__(self, feed, instrument):
        super(MyStrategy, self).__init__(feed, 1000)
        self.__position = [] #None
        self.__instrument = instrument
        self.setUseAdjustedValues(True)
        self.__prices = feed[instrument].getPriceDataSeries()
        self.__sma = ma.SMA(feed[instrument].getPriceDataSeries(), smaPeriod)

    def get_score(self,banana)
        fruit_lover= self.__sma
        return fruit_lover + banana

    def onBars(self, bars):
        for x in bars.getInstruments():

            list_large = {}
            for y in testlist: 
                list_large.update({y : self.get_score(5)})
```

Comment: I've seen quite a few questions like this, search before asking

Comment: I did, I am, actually having a hard time with this...a link would be great...found a few pages but its still not working.

Comment: A function called `get_score` should get / return a score, not set some variables. Along with that point, `{y : self.get_score(5)}` is setting `y` to `None`

Comment: sorry, I didint accurately write the code, just edited it. The get_score function does actually return something and "y" is a variable in the testlist list(at the top of the page).

Comment: Is it possible its the 2 underscores in "self.__sma" that are making it private and therefore inaccessible??

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793517/how-to-transfer-a-parameter-of-a-function-to-another-one/40793574#40793574

Comment: could it be `class` vs `Class`, I can't say for sure if it matters but I've never used an uppercase, I'd write `class MyStrategy...`

Comment: @RageAgainstheMachine Can you please post the full traceback?

Comment: Why are you using names like `self.__sma`?  Why not just `self.sma`?  The object attribute set in method should be usable in all its methods.  Make sure spelling is right.

Answer (score 1):

With a copy of your script, and a bunch of stubs, and too many syntax corrections:

```
testlist = ['TREE', 'HAPPY']
class MyStrategy(): #strategy.BacktestingStrategy):  # lowercase class
    def __init__(self, feed, instrument):
        #super(MyStrategy, self).__init__(feed, 1000)
        self.__position = [] #None
        self.__instrument = instrument
        #self.setUseAdjustedValues(True)
        self.__prices = 123 #feed[instrument].getPriceDataSeries()
        self.__sma = 100 # ma.SMA(feed[instrument].getPriceDataSeries(), smaPeriod)

    def get_score(self,banana):   # add :
        fruit_lover= self.__sma
        return fruit_lover + banana

    def onBars(self, bars):
        #for x in bars.getInstruments():
        list_large = {}
        for y in testlist: 
            list_large.update({y : self.get_score(5)})  
        self.list_large = list_large  # save list_large 
s = MyStrategy('feed', 'inst')
print(vars(s))           # look at attributes set in __init__
print(s.get_score(10))   # test get_score by itself
s.onBars('bars')         # test onBars
print(s.list_large)
```

I get the following run:

```
0009:~/mypy$ python stack40814540.py 
{'_MyStrategy__position': [], 
 '_MyStrategy__instrument': 'inst', 
 '_MyStrategy__sma': 100, 
 '_MyStrategy__prices': 123}
110
{'TREE': 105, 'HAPPY': 105}
```

I have no problem accessing `__sma` attribute in the other methods.

Because the name starts with `__` (and not ending `__`), it is coded as a 'pseudo-private' variable, as can be seen in the `vars` display. But that doesn't harm access from another method.

For a beginner I'd suggest skipping that feature, and just use names like `self.sma`.  Code will be easier to debug.

Make sure you understand my changes; and run some similar tests.